# Wiring an outlet to be controlled by a double switch

Tags: electrical, switch, receptacle

I have an outdoor GFCI receptacle to plug in my pool filter and heater. I am adding a GFCI breaker to my box and putting in a regular receptacle and want to add a double switch above in another single gang box to controll each side of the receptacle. How would I wire this?

Comment: Will these be the only light switch inside a room?

Comment: It will be the only switches on an outside wall

Answer (score 2):

#### Don't use a GFCI receptacle

Mentioning this for future readers, as it sounds like you are already planning on a regular receptacle + GFCI breaker but did mention *another* GFCI receptacle.

Using a GFCI receptacle on a circuit already protected by a GFCI breaker does not add to safety, and could lead to problems if the GFCI ever trips.

In addition, you can't split the two receptacles of a GFCI duplex receptacle - they just aren't designed for that.

So keep the GFCI breaker - which provides critical protection - and use a standard duplex receptacle.

#### Wiring

Assuming typical US cable colors - black/white and black/red/white. If you use conduit, the black and red could be other colors. If you don't use conduit, that means you need to get /3 cable for the connection between the switches and the receptacles. You could do it with two pieces of /2 (and split the neutral) but that would be a bit unusual and could raise questions in the future.

- From panel to switches in switch box

  - Black goes common of switches or, if there is no common, pigtail to one screw on each switch
  - White connects to the white going to the receptacles
- From switches to receptacles in switch box

  - Black goes to one switch
  - Red goes to one switch
  - White connects to the white coming from the panel
- From switches to receptacles in receptacle box

  - Black goes to *hot* side top screw
  - Red goes to *hot* side bottom screw
  - White goes to one screw on the *neutral* side
  - **Remove the tab between the two screws on the hot side**
  - Do not remove the tab on the neutral side

All grounds together and (assuming metal boxes...) to a ground screw in each box.

Comment: Thank you and yes I didn't specify that I was removing the GFCI outlet

Comment: I have /2 wire coming in to the receptacle box. Can I connect neutral to receptacle and then from the switch box run /3 red to line side of switch and black from panel then run white (marked black) to one side of receptacle and black to other side of receptacle